# Which is better? A join or a SELECT IN?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, join

I have a set of ids that I extract using a join of 2 tables.
Now I need some information from 2 other tables. What would normally be the best approach?
So a `SELECT IN` using the set of ids I already have, against each of the other 2 tables OR
Should I try to join these tables to the first 2 I originally do to get the set of IDs?
Is there a standard practice?

Comment: That's impossible to answer because a `JOIN` and an `IN` condition will not necessarily return the same information.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:Why?If the elements in the `IN` are the keys we would join is it not the same?

Comment: See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7d72c/1

Answer (score 1):

Without more information about the size of data, what relevant indexes exist and the number of likely matched that will be in the "IN" list, "it depends" is the best answer you will get. Also I'm assuming you are meaning `SELECT <something> FROM <somewhere> WHERE <column> IN <set>` - if not then my answer will be less relevant. Giving sample queries in your questions will help improve the answers you get in response.

As a general rule though an `IN` clause with static values can not be parametrised so you will end up using ad-hoc SQL which is generally best avoided for a number of reasons.

If you are using `SELECT` within the `IN` clause and you are checking against a column in the inner select that is a primary key or otherwise declared `UNIQUE` then you will often find that the query planner will end up doing the same thing as the simple join (certainly this is often the case with MSSQL) so at that point it is a question of style/preference. I don't know if mySQL would see this equivalence or not: to test this use the `EXPLAIN` method to see what it decides is possible+appropriate.

*Do remember though that the results of `SELECT stuff FROM here WHERE here.property IN (SELECT match FROM there)` could be quite different from `SELECT stuff FROM here JOIN there ON there.match = here.property`* - the above comments are only relevant to circumstances where the two are going to be equivalent. The former will return at most one row for each found in `here` even if there are several rows in `there` where `there.match = here.property` where in the latter case one copy of the row from `here` will be returned for each match found in `there`. Where there is a difference in possible output the decision is made for you: use the one that gives the right result! As another general rule (for which there are exceptions, as always with general rules!) do try avoid using the `JOIN` method with a `DISTINCT` modifier where the `IN` variant would work.

Comment: The OP is about `SELECT <something> FROM <somewhere> WHERE <column> IN <set>` as you say. The `<set>` is foreign keys from the "parent" table

Comment: MySQL's optimizer is known to be bad with sub-selects and `IN` queries. I assume that's one of the reasons so many people out there think that an `IN` is a really bad thing to do. *If* a query using an `IN` with a sub-select is equivalent to a join query most other DBMS will use the same plan anyway (including - but not limted to - MS SQL Server as you have pointed out)

Comment: Hm...I never said that I used a subquery.I already have the IDs selected. So in the IN clause I just have a really really long list of ids

Comment: *You should add to your question that you have a long list of ID (you give no indication of the expected length of that list currently) and the size of the data you will be searching through for matches.* I would generally go with the `JOIN` option for the reason stated above, but data sizes and index structures will make a difference performance-wise. A list of matches given like this will result in an index scan rather than multiple index seeks. Depending on the data you are searching this may or may not be optimal, without more detail all we can really say on that is "benchmark it and see".

Answer (score 1):

What about `EXISTS` standard sql command?

With exists you can limit result with lower cost of hardware(CPU and memory)

[MySQL documentation for EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)